# Angular ui.router not working propely if I use target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my route is working perfectly in my localhost.

I am using this sample but in the sample works well in my local no: http://plnkr.co/edit/AK9uYfpgTIHt9HUdHsjJ?p=preview

If I click in the link: `<li class="active"><a ui-sref="details" target="_blank">Details</a></li>` the page opens blank with no content

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

html:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a ui-sref="details" target="_blank">Details</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="users">users</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="details">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div ui-view></div> 
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

angular:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ["ui.router"])
    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

      // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/details")

      $stateProvider
        .state('details', {
            url: "/details",
            templateUrl: "app/details.html"
        })

        .state('users', {
            url: "/users",
            templateUrl: "app/users.html"
        })
 })
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: i am using this sample but in the sample works well in my local no: http://plnkr.co/edit/AK9uYfpgTIHt9HUdHsjJ?p=preview